# constraint-layout:1.0.0-alpha9 white screen

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout

I switched to the new update for constraint layout and this is what I get, just a white screen

[image]

Thought maybe I'm doing something wrong in my fragment but no it doesn't show any error. So I tried to inspect the layout and this is what I get

[image]

it create the space for the text editors but it doesn't draw anything. here is my XML

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/fragment_login"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/Plum"
    android:clickable="true"
    tools:context=".ui.LoginFragment">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/login_username"
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:hint="@string/Username_or_Email"
        android:inputType="textNoSuggestions|textEmailAddress"
        android:lines="1"
        android:linksClickable="false"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/login_password"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@+id/login_password" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/login_password"
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:hint="@string/password"
        android:inputType="textPassword"
        android:lines="1"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/login_login"
        style="@style/Base.Widget.AppCompat.Button.Colored.login"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:text="@string/login"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/login_password"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@+id/login_password"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/login_password" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/login_singup"
        style="@style/Base.Widget.AppCompat.Button.Colored.signup"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:background="@color/Indigo"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:lines="1"
        android:text="@string/singup"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

I'm not sure what causes the problem. It was working perfectly with alpha 7 :/ any help?

Edit:

The fragment is being created as such:

```
mFragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        mFragmentTransaction = mFragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        switch (fragmentName) {
            case "LoginFragment":
                Log.d(KEY_CLASS_NAME, "createFragment-LoginFragment");
                fragment = new LoginFragment();
                mFragmentTransaction.setCustomAnimations(
                        R.anim.icon_anim_fade_in,
                        R.anim.icon_anim_fade_out,
                        R.anim.icon_anim_fade_in,
                        R.anim.icon_anim_fade_out)
                        .add(R.id.dispatcher_container, fragment, SPKey.KEY_LOGIN_FRAGMENT)
                        .addToBackStack(SPKey.KEY_LOGIN_FRAGMENT)
                        .commit();
                break;
```

The OnCreateView() is implemented as such inside of LoginFragment:

```
@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        mView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_login, container, false);
        if (mView != null) {
            Log.d("LoginFragment", "creating ver");
            mUsername = (EditText) mView.findViewById(R.id.login_username);
            mPassword = (EditText) mView.findViewById(R.id.login_password);
            mLogin = (Button) mView.findViewById(R.id.login_login);
            mSignUp = (Button) mView.findViewById(R.id.login_singup);
            mLogin.setOnClickListener(this);
            mSignUp.setOnClickListener(this);
            Log.d("LoginFragment", "done creating ver");
        } else {
            Log.d("LoginFragment", "mView is empty");
        }
        return mView;
    }
```

Also, I just discovered that SDK manager in Android Studio 2.2.1 downloads "m2repository" inside of "~\Android\sdk\extras", but if you use Standalone SDK manager it puts the "m2repository" inside of "~\Android\sdk\extras\android". I don't know if that matters but that's where constraint-layout folder is.

Comment: It seems to work for me if I paste your XML in a ConstraintLayout -- can you explain more how you are using this code? you mentioned fragments? what are the attributes of the ConstraintLayout itself, or of the fragment?

Comment: Alpha 7 works completely fine, but alpha 8 and alpha 9 will show the above ... I thought I might done something wrong in my fragment so I made a new fragment and still the same white page ... I should also mention that I tried to "Invalidate Catches/Restart ..." but no hope :/ if you may suggest any solution, I would be happy to try it and make a post here with the results :)

Comment: Yes, but what do you mean by using fragments and constraintlayout? could you put the code / xml on what you are doing? as I said, simply copy pasting what you have above works in a ConstraintLayout (same if in a fragment)

Comment: I edited my post ... hope that helps

Comment: I tried to replicate what you have, but it still works -- what is the layout you are putting the fragment in (I just used a vertical linearlayout and a framelayout for my test) ? and with which params? Else, which version of android are you using? (I tried on a Nexus 6 API 23 emulator). The only difference I may have is had to add the fragment transaction in the activity using  mFragmentTransaction.add(R.id.dispatcher_container, fragment, "LoginFragment").addToBackStack("LoginFragment").commit(); as I didn't have your anims, but that really shouldn't make a difference.

Comment: Could you file a bug on code.google.com so we can get to the bottom of this? thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Following is the example of use of Constraint Layout,

XML,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                                             xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                                             android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                             android:layout_height="match_parent"
                                             android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                                             android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                                             android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                                             android:layout_margin="16dp">

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/login_username"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="Email"
    android:inputType="textNoSuggestions|textEmailAddress"
    android:lines="1"
    android:linksClickable="false"/>

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/login_password"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="Password"
    android:inputType="textPassword"
    android:lines="1"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/login_username"/>

<android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton
    android:id="@+id/login_login"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Login"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/login_password"/>

<android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton
    android:id="@+id/login_singup"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:lines="1"
    android:text="Signup"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/login_login"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/login_password"/>
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

And Output,

https://i.stack.imgur.com/iCtwm.png

Hopefully this will help you

Cheers!!!

Comment: This doesn't tell me what is wrong with my code !? if I face this again, how would I fix it !?

Comment: By Default, when you put the ConstraintLayout it will take absolute location on canvas. Just remove that and change as per your requirement.

Answer (score 1):

yeah stupid bug. Downgrade the Constraint Layout to 7, then it should work

go to your  gradle and replace

compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.0-alpha9'

with

compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.0-alpha7'

not sure why this solves it

Comment: is it a know bug? I don't know how to look if it's known or not :/ and I already rolled back to alpha 7 :)

Comment: haven't found much. But you are not the only one who has that problem (makes me more calm, too :-P )

Comment: @Makaveli if you have repro steps, please file a bug :)

Answer (score 0):

We just published ConstraintLayout beta 1, which fixed several issues that might have explained your bug.

While I couldn't replicate your exact issue, please update and check if beta 1 does solves it -- I'd love to confirm that it is the case.

Thanks!

Comment: Nothing changed, still the same as the 2 pictures above. The alpha-7 still works fine. where should I go to submit a bug report :/

Comment: That's unfortunate :-/ You can file a bug report on https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/entry -- if you could point to a project, or xml repro case, that would be excessively useful. Thanks!

Comment: I'll do my best with filing the bug

Comment: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=227448&q=constraint%20layout&colspec=ID%20Status%20Priority%20Owner%20Summary%20Stars%20Reporter%20Opened